# MySQL select children where parent has a value (best query)

Tags: mysql

Someone on stackoverflow asked how to select all children where the parent has a certain value.

I came up with this answer:

```
SELECT label, parent_id 
FROM folders 
WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM folders WHERE uniq='w2d4f6')
```

Someone else answered this idea:

```
SELECT b.label, b.parent_id
FROM folders a, folders b
WHERE a.uniq = 'w2d4f6' AND b.parent_id = a.id
```

The result of these queries is the same.

When I use EXPLAIN on these queries they both use 2 subqueries. Now I was wondering what query is the best option (looking at performance) in situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best query would be

```
SELECT b.label, b.parent_id
FROM folders a
INNER JOIN folders b ON b.parent_id = a.id
WHERE a.uniq = 'w2d4f6'
```

It should have the same execution plan as the second query you provided, but it's ANSI-92 SQL compliant.

`JOIN`s are usually more efficient than nested queries, but that depends on lots of other parameters (indexes being only one of them).

Comment: So with an index on parent_id and id as a primary key this should normally be the fastest way? This was exacly what I was looking for since I use these queries quite often.